# How to convert a seewave spectrogram into a wav file

Tags: r, audio, spectrogram

I would like to manipulate a `seewave` audio spectrogram and then convert it back to a `.wav` file.
A quick example

```
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)

data(tico)
#generate spectrogram with phase information
spec_tico=spectro(tico,plot=FALSE,complex=TRUE,norm=FALSE,dB=NULL)
#manipulate spectrogram
spec_tico_new=dostuff(spec_tico)
#convert back into Wave object - but there is no function spectr2Wave!
tico_new=spectr2Wave(spec_tico_new,...)
```

I haven't been able to find anything close to `spectr2Wave` in the `seewave` documentation.

Do you guys know a way how to convert it back without digging into the `wav` file specs and doing it manually? Thank you!

Comment: @Vlo I use `complex=TRUE` - so I will get complex numbers from the FFT. I should be able to obtain the phase from the complex numbers.

Comment: @Vlo I am not sure whether you get notified by this comment since you have deleted your comment - but just in case you are interested: I have found a solution. And thank you for your interesting link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turned out to be relatively simple! The important keyword that I was missing is "short-time Fourier transformation" - that is what `seewave::spectro` basically does. After googling for "*inverse* short-time Fourier transformation" the `seewave` function `istft` showed up.

```
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)

data(tico)
#generate spectrogram with phase information
spec_tico=spectro(tico,plot=FALSE,complex=TRUE,norm=FALSE,dB=NULL,ovlp=50)
#convert back into Wave object
tico_new=istft(spec_tico$amp,f=tico@samp.rate,ovlp=50,wl=512,output = "Wave")
```

Now enjoy the sound of Zonotrichia capensis(*)

```
#play on Windows
play(tico_new)
#play on Linux with vlc (or any other player ...)
play(tico_new,player="cvlc")
#on Linux you have to kill the two vlc processES afterwards!
```

(*) that's the bird that you can hear if you execute the `play` command. :)

Comment: or `listen` command if `play` isn't set up properly by default for your OS.